# GRID-file: get max extent for all z-values above given value

Tags: python, gdal, extents, gmt

I have a GRID-file with a quite large extent.
For an automatic workflow I need the maximum extent/bounding-box for all z-values that are over a certain range.
For example: Get the maximum extent for all z-values that are greater or equal than 0.05

Is there a possibility to do that with Python, GDAL or GMT-tools (generic mapping tools), so that it can run automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not the best solution but solved the problem for me. For anybody who wants to know how I did it:

```
gdal_contour -i 1000 -off 0.05 input.grd output.shp
```

-i = some very high number 
-off = minimum pixel value

then:

```
ogrinfo -al -so output.shp
```

and parse the ogrinfo output to get the extent coords

EDIT
Better Solution (Python3 with Subprocess):

```
gdal_calc.py -A input.grd --oufile=temp.tif --calc=logical_an(A>=min, A<=max)
gdal_polygonize.py temp.tif -f GMT temp.gmt
```

with Python3:

```
gmt_file = open(temp.gmt)
extent_temp = gmt_file.readlines[1]
extent = re.findall("(-?\d+.\d+)",extent_temp)

west = extent_w_time[0]   
east = extent_w_time[1]   
south = extent_w_time[2]   
north = extent_w_time[3]
```